# How to run Nuget Package Manager Host in cmd / powershell

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I am currently using *Update-Package* command in Visual Studio 2017 Nuget Package Manager Console. I need to use it from command prompt

eg:

```
nuget Update-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visual Studio's Package Manager Console is only available in Visual Studio. The NuGet cmdlets interacts with Visual Studio itself to read/modify your project file, so that implementation can't work as-is in other powershell hosts.

If your goal is just to script updates to packages, as long as you're not impacted by any [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference#limitations) or [package compatibility issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference#package-compatibility-issues), you can consider migrating to SDK-style projects and `PackageReference` instead of `packages.config`, then you can use [`dotnet outdated`](https://github.com/dotnet-outdated/dotnet-outdated) to script your updates.

Answer (score 3):

You can follow the below guidelines by Microsoft:

1) Visit nuget.org/downloads and select NuGet 3.3 or higher (2.8.6 is not compatible with Mono). The latest version is always recommended, and 4.1.0+ is required to publish packages to nuget.org.

2)  Each download is the nuget.exe file directly. Instruct your browser to save the file to a folder of your choice. The file is not an installer; you won't see anything if you run it directly from the browser.

3) Add the folder where you placed nuget.exe to your PATH environment variable to use the CLI tool from anywhere.

So, basically in your computer properties > Global Variables, you need to add path of Nuget.exe and then you can run the Nuget commands from Command Line Interface.

For further Clarifications you can refer link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference

Comment: You may refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-update for update